# Show that $\mathbb{A}^2 \cong \mathbb{A}^1 \times \mathbb{A}^1$ as varieties.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Show that $\mathbb{A}^2 \cong \mathbb{A}^1 \times \mathbb{A}^1$ as varieties.

I know how to do this in the case of **affine** varieties. Since $\mathbb{A}^1 \times \mathbb{A}^1$ is a product in the category of affine varieties, its coordinate ring $k[\mathbb{A}^1 \times \mathbb{A}^1]$ is isomorphic to $k[x]\otimes_k k[y]$, a co-product in the category of $k$-algebras. Since $k[\mathbb{A}^2]\cong k[x,y] \cong k[x]\otimes_k k[y]$ as $k$-algebras, we are done.

How do I generalize this to varieties? Thanks.

Comment: If $Y$ is an affine variety and $X$ any variety then morphisms $X \to Y$ correspond to maps of $k$-algebras $A(Y) \to \mathcal{O}(X)$ [I'm using Hartsthorne's notation]. If you have this fact then you don't have to change your proof so much.

Comment: @Hoot if I use this fact, isn't my proof the same? I thought $\mathcal{O}(X)=A(X)$ if $X$ is affine? Also, where can I find this fact in Hartshorne?

Comment: It should be be somewhere in I.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me just rephrase what **Hoot** has already said in the comments.

Namely, suppose that $X$ is some $k$-variety, and we have morphisms $f,g:X\to \mathbb{A}^1$. Then, these correspond to $k$-algebra maps $f^\ast,g^\ast:k[x]\to\mathcal{O}_X(X)$. Thus, they factor uniquely through the map $f^\ast\otimes g^\ast:k[x,y]\to \mathcal{O}_X(X)$ which corresponds to a map $X\to\mathbb{A}^2$ giving you the result.

In slightly fancier language, notice that we have functors

$$\left(k\mathsf{-Varieties}\right)^\text{op}\overset{\displaystyle \overset{\mathrm{Spec}}{\longleftarrow}}{\underset{\Gamma}{\longrightarrow}}k\mathsf{-Algebras}$$

Which are adjoints of one another:

$$\mathrm{Hom}_{(k\mathsf{-Varieties})^\text{op}}(\mathrm{Spec}(A),X)=\mathrm{Hom}_{k\mathsf{-Algebras}}(A,\Gamma(X))$$

In particular, we see that $\mathrm{Spec}$ is a left-adjoint, and so by basic category theory $\mathrm{Spec}(A\sqcup B)=\mathrm{Spec}(A)\sqcup \mathrm{Spec}(B)$ where I am using $\sqcup$ to denote the arbitrary notion of coproduct. But, what is the coproduct in $k\mathsf{-Algebras}$? It's just tensor product! So, this says that

$$\mathrm{Spec}(A\otimes_k B)=\mathrm{Spec}(A)\sqcup\mathrm{Spec}(B)$$

where, be careful, as we've set it up, the coproduct on the right hand side is the coproduct in the ***opposite*** category of $k\mathsf{-Varieties}$! But, a coproduct in the opposite category is just a product in the original category. Thus, we see that

$$\mathrm{Spec}(A\otimes_k B)=\mathrm{Spec}(A)\times\mathrm{Spec}(B)$$

where the right hand side is now the product in the honest category $k\mathsf{-Varieties}$—i.e. fiber product over $k$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are stating the facts that I used in my proof above. Are you saying that being isomorphic as affine varieties implies isomorphic as varieties?

Comment: @Michael Certainly. Affine varieties is a full-subcategory of varieties. The morphisms between affine varieties are the same whether you think of them as affine varieties or just varieties. Thus, they are isomorphic indpendent of which generality you think of them in. The whole point is that morphisms TO affine varieties FROM anything factor through affine varieties. So, morphisms to affine varieties essentially are a purely affine thing, even if the source is itself not affine.

Comment: The real subtlety is in whether the product of affine $k$-varieties is the same as the product of $k$-varieties. (They are. For comparison, infinite coproducts are not the same.)